# Mongodb Aggregation pipeline is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using the MongoDB Aggregation pipeline with mongoose it's not working instead it's returning an error in the catch block. After matching I want to get average ratings, average price, min price and max price.

```
exports.getTourStats = async (req, res) => {
try {

    const stats = await Tour.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { $ratingsAverage: { $gte: 4.5 } }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                avgRating: { $avg: '$ratingsAverage' },
                avgPrice: { $avg: '$price' },
                minPrice: { $min: '$price' },
                maxPrice: { $max: '$price' },
            }
        }
    ]);

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Success',
        data: {
            stats
        },
    });

} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
        message: err
    })
}
```

}

Error:

```
"message": {
        "ok": 0,
        "code": 2,
        "codeName": "BadValue"
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the match stage should be something like this : `$match: { ratingsAverage: { $gte: 4.5 } }`

Comment: remove the coma after maxPrice: { $max: '$price' }